# How can I access runtime environment variables from a webpack-compiled script that runs in node?

Tags: node.js, webpack, environment-variables, runtime, server-side

We package and ship a web server that runs in node, using webpack (an admittedly unusual scenario).

In this web server, I would like to access runtime environment variables, not the environment variables from the compile-time run of webpack. However, `process.env` just contains `{ NODE_ENV: 'development' }`.

Is there some way of accessing the actual runtime process's environment?

Comment: I tried using `new LoaderOptionsPlugin({options: {extendEnv: false,}}),` in the webpack config, as the code looked like that should be respected, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The replacement of `process.env` is actually done by changing code that accesses that variable. If you access it programmatically in a way that avoids this, you will be able to use the underlying variable which is still present:

```
// avoid cunning webpack replacement of process.env code
let process_env = {}
for (var a of ['env']) {
  process_env = process[a]
}
console.log(process.env.HOME) // this gives undefined
console.log(process_env.HOME) // this works
```